# function array_multisort in php change the key of my array

Tags: php, arrays, function, array-multisort

I have this array:

```
$array["4E-952778"][0]['fileName'] = "File 1";
$array["4E-952778"][0]['product'] = "Muse On Demand";
$array["4E-952778"][1]['fileName'] = "File 2";
$array["4E-952778"][1]['product'] = "Muse On Demand";   

$array["15210"][0]['fileName'] = "File 3";
$array["15210"][0]['product'] = "4Manager"; 
$array["15210"][1]['fileName'] = "File 4";
$array["15210"][1]['product'] = "4Manager";

$products = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
    $products[$key] = $row[0]['product'];       
}
array_multisort($products, SORT_ASC, $array);

print_r($array);
```

and the result is this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [fileName] => File 3
                    [product] => 4Manager
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [fileName] => File 4
                    [product] => 4Manager
                )

        )
    [4E-952778] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [fileName] => File 1
                    [product] => Muse On Demand
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [fileName] => File 2
                    [product] => Muse On Demand
                )
        )
)
```

As you can observe the function `array_multisort()` change the key: `15210` to `0` why this change?

Comment: Read the manual! `Associative (string) keys will be maintained,` **but numeric keys will be re-indexed.**

Comment: so how can i preserve the key 15210 ?

Comment: Add a few letters around it that it isn't numeric

Comment: is there any other way to do this because i shouldn't modify the keys ?

Comment: Try `asort()` instead of `array_multisort()`, does that do the trick for you?

Comment: it fix it but i shoud use  `array_multisort() ` because im using it to sort another array as i see in this link: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)

Comment: If the answers below doesn't solve your problem then please post an example with multiple arrays and your expected output

Comment: i changed the code so you can see my original problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution to this problem

```
uasort($array, function ($a, $b) {
 $i=0;
 return strcmp($a[$i]['product'], $b[$i]['product']);
```

});

Answer (score 4):

A quote from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php):

> Associative (string) keys will be maintained, **but numeric keys will be re-indexed.**

And PHP is automatically casting your string "15210" to an integer.

The trick for that to work is to add a "0" to the key ("015210"), it will force the type casting to (string).

If want to read more about this see: [Bug #21788    array_multisort() changes array keys unexpectedly given numeric strings as keys](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=21788)

Comment: the problem is that i can't modify the keys

Comment: Well a nice little trick I wasn't aware of until know, but sadly it doesn't solve OP's problems

Comment: I can tell you to perform a loop on the array and check for every item before you make the sorting. But it's not a good solution i think. Can you tell us why you can't modify the keys?

Comment: because after that i should print the keys with the values and it should be 15210 and not 015210

Comment: Simple, after you sort your keys, you replace them another time to get the initial values. If you don't have performance constraints go for it.

Comment: that's not a solution for my project, it should be done efficiently